# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el valor de una variable al pulsar un botón?

Tags: botón, onclick

soy novato programando y quisiera cambiar el valor de una variable (en este caso llamada start, y al pulsar quiero cambiar su valor a 0 para que actúe) pero no me funciona. ¿Alguien puede señalar mi error? Gracias.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="micss.css">

        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
        </head>

        <body>
          <script src="mijavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
           <button id="demo" autofocus onclick="boton()" title="boton" id="boton" 



           </button>


    </body>


</html>




//javascript//
let start;
start = 1;
function boton() {start = 0};
let tipo;
if (start === 0) {tipo = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)};
```

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido a esto de la programación :). Te comento la duda:

Lee el código y verás el error:

- primera ejecución (cuando carga la página)

  1. Se declara la variable start
  2. Se inicializa start = 1
  3. Se crea la función boton()
  4. Se declara tipo
  5. ¿start == 0? Entonces crea un número aleatorio
     (En el punto 5 está el fallo, start nunca va a ser 0 en la primera ejecucion )
- segunda ejecución (cuando se pulsa el button)

  1. boton() (que solo pone start === 0)

Si quieres cambiar el valor de tipo, deberías revisar el punto 5 e intentar que haga eso en la segunda ejecución.

¡Espero que te haya servido de ayuda!

Un saludo

Comment: Hola @Gorrion la variable tipo es para otra cosa posterior, simplemente la creo para que se le asigne un valor aleatorio. A grandes rasgos quiero que al pulsar el boton se cambie la variable start de 1 a 0 para que genere un valor aleatorio a la variable tipo. Además la cosa está en que yo quiero que la variable haga que se genere un numero aleatorio solo al pulsar el boton y por eso le asigno valor 1 al cargar la pagina (para que no genere numero aleatorio hasta pulsar el boton).

Comment: Para generar en tipo un valor aleatorio al pulsar el boton, prueba este codigo ( la primera ejecucion declara la funcion no la hace)
 
let tipo;
function boton() {tipo = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)};